# Multiprocess error while using map function in python with N-Gram language model

Tags: python, multiprocessing, speech-to-text, n-gram

I wanna increase the accuracy of my speech2text model with using a N-Gram. So i'm using this line of code to apply the function on the whole dataset as below:

```
result = dataset.map(predict, batch_size=5, num_proc=int(os.environ.get('cpu_core')))
```

The CPU core I set for `'cpu_core'` is 8.

Here is the `predict` function code:

```
def predict(batch):
     batch["predicted"] = processor.batch_decode(np.array(batch["logits"])).text[0]
     print(batch["predicted"])
     return batch
```

I'm using this line in a `try` block, which is in a `while True` loop and when the program will face a multiprocess error, it will stuck in the `while true` loop. Here is the complete code:

```
while True:

    try:
        dataset = dataset.map(speech_file_to_array_fn)

        # If we're using n-gram
        if os.environ.get('active_ngram') == '1':

            dataset = dataset.map(predict_model)

        print("\nN-Gram started\n")
        result = dataset.map(predict, batch_size=5, num_proc=int(os.environ.get('cpu_core'))) # This is the line that occurs the error

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('interrupted!')
        break  

    except:
        pass
```

Now I want to know how can i handle this multiprocess error. (python 3.8.10 & ubuntu 20.04.4)

here is the error:

> ^CProcess
> ForkPoolWorker-3335:█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████Process
> ForkPoolWorker-3330:██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████|
> 3/3 [02:08<00:00, 37.41s/ex] Process ForkPoolWorker-19: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-3333: Process ForkPoolWorker-16: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-21: Process ForkPoolWorker-13: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-15: Process ForkPoolWorker-12: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-14: Process ForkPoolWorker-3336: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-3331: Process ForkPoolWorker-3334: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-3332: Process ForkPoolWorker-18: Process
> ForkPoolWorker-17:  #0:
> 25%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▌
> | 1/4 [14:09:32<42:28:38, 50972.67s/ex] Process ForkPoolWorker-20:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 356, in get
> res = self._reader.recv_bytes()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in
> recv_bytes
> buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in
> _recv_bytes
> buf = self._recv(4)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
> chunk = read(handle, remaining) KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last): Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 114, in worker
> task = get()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 355, in get
> with self._rlock:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 95, in
> **enter**
> return self._semlock.**enter**() KeyboardInterrupt interrupted! ^C

Comment: You are ignoring the errors with `except pass`. Can you please do: `except Exception as e: print(e)` , and see the error that you get

Comment: @VeyselOlgun I tried to get the error as an output but for now It didn't happen. I will post the error as soon as it occurs again

Comment: @VeyselOlgun Here is the error that i got:

`  
File "/home/mirafzali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/connection.py", line 371, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "/home/mirafzali/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/connection.py", line 371, in _send
    n = write(self._handle, buf)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this error. The `BrokenPipeError: [Error 32] broken pipe` arises from the Linux operating system and it will occur when you are doing IO tasks. Specifically, when the pipeline of read and write on Linux is closed, as the other side of communication, is still trying to read or write the data, this error will occur.

Now the fun part is here: I was using 6 `workers` which was the number of `CPU cores` in my map function. The length of data in the `dataset` iterable was 25. So the pipeline doing the map function had 5 rows with 4 files in each and **1 row with 5 files**. I guess it was the cause of the error while the last row with 5 files made some disturbance. So I reduced the number of files in the dataset from *25* to *24* and the number of workers to *6* and removed the `batch_size=5`. This made the length of the data to be divisible by the number of processes and made the error go away. [Here](https://linuxpip.org/broken-pipe-python-error/) is the link for more information about `BrokenPipeline Error`.